# select date from table and display it in different formats using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hy all..I have a table where I'm storing the date in the following format: 'YYYY-mm-dd 00-00-00'. Now I want to make a select statement and display all records where date is BETWEEN the dates i give. Like this:

```
$c=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM useri where data_creare_user BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND '20120-06-05' ");   

$d=mysql_fetch_array($c);

echo $d['nume'];
```

I know that I have to convert somehow the date from the table but I can't seem to figure it out.Can you tell me hoe to display the records based on that select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `data_creare_user` column is not in a suitable [temporal data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) data type, it should be.  Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   useri
WHERE  DATE(data_creare_user) BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND '2012-06-05'
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using a VARCHAR to hold your dates as string. If you can change the schema, you might be better off using a DATE or DATETIME type. That said, MySQL provides the function `STR_TO_DATE()` to help with this. Your query would then look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM useri WHERE STR_TO_DATE(data_creare_user, '%Y-%m-%d %H-%i-%s') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2012-06-01', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('20120-06-05','%Y-%m-%d');
```